# How can I create a Dockerfile FROM an Image in Azure Container Registry?

Tags: azure, docker

I've pushed an Image (which is a version of R + some libraries) on my private Azure Container Registry. How can build an Image starting from this Image?

In other words, I want to do "FROM registry/env:version" but I'm pretty sure that I need to use other settings to access my repository.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You should login your Docker daemon to your Azure Container Registry using the following command : `docker login myregistry.azurecr.io --username $SP_APP_ID --password $SP_PASSWD`

Then, using the fully qualified path for your image in the Dockerfile should work automatically, as long as the identity provided in the first step (login) has the rights to pull this image.

Comment: You mean that I should use RUN docker login ... before the FROM? Furthermore, what are SP_APP_ID and SP_PASSWD?

Comment: No - the dockerfile, keep it like you intended to do. Then, everything which comes next happens during the build phase. For the Docker daemon to be able to pull this FROM reference you put in the Dockerfile, you need to provide credentials for it to get access to the Container Registry. SP stands for Service Principal if you use one, but you could use your own credentials if that is suitable for your case.

Comment: Ok thanks, I get it! It works!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm trying to figure out your answer, I'm trying to pull a docker image from my Azure Container Registry and build it and push it back to a new repository. I'm starting my Dockerfile as

```
FROM xxxxxx.azurecr.io/php-7.4:latest AS compiled
```

how to configure the docker daemon in azure pipelines world?